# mojarra is JSF and is in glassfish?

Tags: jsf, glassfish, facelets, mojarra

My understanding is that Mojarra is the reference implementation for JSF, and, because Glassfish bundles Mojarra, there's no need to include JSF JAR's on the classpath when using Glassfish.  Is this a correct understanding?

The upshot being that, [when running facelets on glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26083887/262852), there's no need to add JAR's for basic facelets functionality.

Comment: I think that correct. Waiting for other comment.

Comment: thanks, that was my reading from wikipedia.  wanted to make sure.